# Finding values of two variables of a curve.

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Given that the curve $y=ax^2+b/x$ has a gradient of $-5$ at point $(2,-2)$, what are the values of $a$ and $b$?

I'm not sure how to come at this question, I derived the original equation and I got:  $y'=2ax-b/x^2$. I think you need to do simultaneous equations but again I have no idea how to come at this question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here's an admittedly rather long but extremely helpful guide to MathJax, for formatting the math in your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track! You've got two unknowns, $a$ and $b$, and two equations: $$\begin{align}y&=ax^2+\frac{b}{x}\\y'&=2ax-\frac{b}{x^2}\end{align}$$

The problem tells you that $x=2$ and $y=-2$, and that at that point, $y'=5$, so you can plug all those values into the above two equations and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Im confused about plugging it in first time doing simultaneous equations, if i plug in the y value and x value into both equations a and b are still left so how could i solve?? or do i replace either a or b with the gradient 5?

Comment: Plugging in $2$ for $x$, $-2$ for $y$, and $5$ for $y'$, you'll end up with these equations:$$\begin{align}-2&=4a+\frac12b\\5&=4a-\frac14b\end{align}$$

If you're doing calculus, you'll want to have a good idea of how to do solve simultaneous equations (otherwise known as systems of equations), and [this video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/systems-of-linear-equations/modal/v/trolls-tolls-and-systems-of-equations) gives you a good introduction.